# Global Socket Starts (AsyncSocket)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asyncsocket

I'm trying to start a socket from another class (Not in the "applicationDidFinishLaunching"), so, in the **AppDelegate.m** I'm calling the class netClass:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    netClass *network = [[netClass alloc] init];
    [network startNet];
}
```

And in the **netClass**, the method startNet starts the socket normally:

```
- (void)startNet 
{
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
    ...
    [netService publish];
}
```

But the methods of asyncSocket in the netClass, as "didAcceptNewSocket", "socketDidDisconnect", "netServiceDidPublish", are not being called.

Any idea how to call it?

Any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: What is `netClass`?  It's likely that you're not setting the delegate.

Comment: `netClass` is another class that I created to start my connection and deal with the delegate methods. In the .h file I set the delegate, like `NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSNetServiceDelegate, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>`, but it isn't working. Any idea, Stephen?

Comment: @Alberto: That isn't setting the delegate; that's declaring that instances of that class *can be* those kinds of delegate. Declaring that any instance can be a delegate of certain kinds of object does not make a specific instance actually a delegate of a specific other object.

Comment: @PeterHosey, sorry, actually, I also added `[netService setDelegate:self];`, but it's not working! Incredibly strange!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate by sending a `setDelegate:` message to whatever your NSNetService object is -- it looks like from the code you posted, that that is "`netService`" (`[netService setDelegate:self];`).

Putting "`NSApplicationDelegate, NSNetServiceDelegate, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate`" in your .h file doesn't set the delegate, it's basically just letting the compiler know that you intend to implement the methods of those protocols. Also, you should not have `NSApplicationDelegate` there, since you already have an app delegate.

Comment: That's why it's funny: In the AppDelegate I don't need to set it (`[netService setDelegate:self];`, and it work normally, calling the delegate methods, and in my class (netClass), even putting the `setDelegate` it don't works!

PS: `NSApplicationDelegate` removed. :-)

Comment: @Alberto: The NSNetService can't be “calling the delegate methods” of something that isn't its delegate. If you mean the NSApplicationDelegate methods, those are unrelated: The NSApplication sends messages listed in the NSApplicationDelegate protocol to its delegate, and the NSNetService sends messages listed in the NSNetServiceDelegate protocol to its delegate. Make sure your “`netClass`” (which really needs a better name) instance has actually created the NSNetService.

Comment: Actually, it's called JSNetwork, netClass just to make it easy. :-D. I was wrong: In the AppDelegate `applicationDidFini[...]` I call `[netService setDelegate:self];`, but calling it from "netClass" it don't work. It's really weird: Same code, same delegates, same methods, different actions. I'll take a better look in the internet. If I find anything really relevant, I'll post it here. Thanks, @PeterHosey.

Comment: @Alberto: In which class are you putting the NSNetServiceDelegate methods?

Comment: It's hard to say what to do now without seeing more code in your JSNetwork class.  Did you take the [netService setDelegate:self] out of the app delegate?  You can't have 2 objects be the delegate of something, it should only be in the JSNetwork class. I'm not sure whether that setDelegate message should be sent to netService though, since you didn't show the code for that class.